# Enable https in jboss as 7.1.1 and import ssl certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jboss

I have a web application in deployed on jboss as 7.1.1 and its working fine. Now i want to enable ssl to my jboss server. i want to access my portal using this

**https://myapplication.com**

For this i went through https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/ssl.html documentation.
I did some modification in standalone.xml file also.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <configuration>
            <static-resources listings="true"/>
        </configuration>
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="443"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https">
            <ssl name="https" password="pro@123" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/pro.com.jks"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

I can access http://myapplication.com but cant access https://myapplication.com

I bought certificate also but dont know where to configure now to access my portal in http secure mode.

when i see console this comes

```
08:10:46,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.binding.connect (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.connector.https]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take a look in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide, you need set key-alias property if you use a keystore, the default value used is tomcat.